# how to solve google speech recognition network error

Tags: google-speech-api

I used to google speech recognition api in annyang.js.

Google speech recognition sometimes error occurs "network".

How to solve this error?

I don't know why this error occurred...

My local(korea) time 16:05 before error not occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I think the network error is because of quotas on Google Speech API. Only 50 requests per day are provided for free. Once you are done with the requests, it starts throwing the network error. Check your developer console to see if this the case.